# TestCafe only running first test in loop

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have the following function to run parameterized tests:

```
export function multiTest<T>({cases, setup, testFn, testNamePrefix, skip, options: _options}: {
  cases: TestCases<T>
  setup: (t: SetupHelper, cases: TestCases<T>) => (void | Promise<void>) 
  testFn: MultiTestFn<T>,
  testNamePrefix?: string,
  skip?: boolean
  options?: HelperOptions
}): Promise<void> {
  const doSetup = async () => {
    if (skip) {
      return;
    }

    // some setup code here left out

    await setup(new SetupHelper(options), cases);
  }

  let wrappedFn = test.page(someUrl);
  if(skip) {
    wrappedFn = wrappedFn.skip;
  }

  let didSetup = false;
  cases.forEach(([testName, caseData]) => {
    wrappedFn(`${testNamePrefix || ""}${testName}`, async (t) => {
      if(!didSetup) {
        await doSetup();
        didSetup = true;
      }
      await testFn(t, new Helper(t, options), caseData)
    })
  });
}
```

The test code that calls this:

```
skeleton.multiTest({
  testNamePrefix: "Content masking: ",
  cases: [
    { suppressMessages: "off", suppressTypes: "all", expectedMasks: 0},
    { suppressMessages: "all", suppressTypes: "all", expectedMasks: 12},
    { suppressMessages: "otherOnly", suppressTypes: "all", expectedMasks: 6 },
    { suppressMessages: "all", suppressTypes: "links", expectedMasks: 2 },
    { suppressMessages: "all", suppressTypes: "phones", expectedmasks: 4, replacement: "" },
    { suppressMessages: "all", suppressTypes: "emails", expectedMasks: 6, replacement: "[TEST]" },
  ].map(makeFullCase),
  setup: setup,
  testFn: async (t, s, testCase) => {
      await t.expect(/* ... */)
  }
});
```

I feel like this does essentially the same thing as the data driven test example described here: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402804/recipes/best-practices/create-data-driven-tests

Yet testCafe seems to run only one of the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot wrap `test` in this way. Each first call of `test` creates a `Test` instance. You do this only once and reuse one instance many times, but one instance can keep information only about one test.

Try rewriting your `multiTest` function as follows:

```
export function multiTest<T>({cases, setup, testFn, testNamePrefix, skip, options: _options}: {
  cases: TestCases<T>
  setup: (t: SetupHelper, cases: TestCases<T>) => (void | Promise<void>) 
  testFn: MultiTestFn<T>,
  testNamePrefix?: string,
  skip?: boolean
  options?: HelperOptions
}): Promise<void> {
  const doSetup = async () => {
    if (skip) {
      return;
    }

    // some setup code here left out

    await setup(new SetupHelper(options), cases);
  }

  let didSetup = false;
  cases.forEach(([testName, caseData]) => {
    let wrappedFn = test.page(someUrl);
    if(skip) {
      wrappedFn = wrappedFn.skip;
    }

    wrappedFn(`${testNamePrefix || ""}${testName}`, async (t) => {
      if(!didSetup) {
        await doSetup();
        didSetup = true;
      }
      await testFn(t, new Helper(t, options), caseData)
    })
  });
}
```